# Laravel pagination with comments

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5

I'm building a ticket system. A ticket can have multiple comments. But how can I paginate this right?

This is my controller:

```
public function showTicket($slug)
{
     $ticket = Ticket::whereSlug($slug);
     if(Auth::user()->id == $ticket->user_id)
     {
        return view('users.ticket')->with('ticket',$ticket);
     }
}
```

This is my view right now:

```
 @foreach($ticket->reactions as $reaction)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><strong>{!! ucfirst($reaction->user->name) !!}  {!! $reaction->user->lastname !!}<span class="pull-right">{!! $reaction->created_at !!}</span></strong></div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                       {!! $reaction->content !!}
        </div>
   </div>
 @endforeach
```

When I say in my controller:

```
$ticket = Ticket::whereSlug($slug)->paginate(15);
```

and in my view:

```
{!! $ticket->reactions->render() !!}
```

It's not working.

Comment: what error do you get when you render not working ?

Comment: I receive the error: ErrorException in UserTicketsController.php line 73:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$user_id

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
function showTicket($slug) 
{
    $ticket = Thicket::whereSlug($slug)->first();
    $reactions = $thicket->reactions()->paginate(15);

    if(Auth::user()->id == $ticket->user_id)
        return view('users.ticket', compact('ticket', 'reactions'));
}
```

and in your view

```
@foreach($reactions as $reaction)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><strong>{!! ucfirst($reaction->user->name) !!}  {!! $reaction->user->lastname !!}<span class="pull-right">{!! $reaction->created_at !!}</span></strong></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                {!! $reaction->content !!}
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```